# how to publish facebook apps for users

Tags: php, facebook

I have developed a facebook apps in php first time. Its working properly. This app running only for my account,I cant understand how to publish this apps for my friends or users.I go to privacy settings->App Settings and set 'Everyone' on 'Posts on your behalf', but its not working. Please help...

Comment: As long as your app is public (not in sandbox mode) it is live. What else do you want to do?

Comment: The settings you are talking about are for posts etc. made _through_ your app. If you want your friends/other people to “see” _the app itself_ and be able to use it – then take it out of sandbox mode.

Comment: Does your app runs in a tab in a facebook page, or does it run as a separate website?

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't installed your ssl on your server. Facebook need https for application. It would be better if you will post your url here.

Comment: Please give your app url like htp://apps.facebook.com/yourappname